# Route Mapping in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

As I learned, the default `MVC` route mapping is

```
http://<domain>/{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

Is there any problem if i change this as below? Is it work correctly?

```
http://<domain>/{action}/{controller}/{id}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You determine the convention you want to use. Once you commit to follow it and that it doesn't cause confusion

Comment: There is No problem doing it that way. Its the feature provided by MVC. you can also have route  `likehttp://<domain>/Nayana/{action}/{controller}/{id}` and whole lot more stuff..

Answer (score 0):

Your change should work fine. Just remember that the calling convention for your action will also change.

Comment: Global.asax?? Are you sure??

Comment: Oops. I went according to : http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs